# Transaction propagation from CDI to EJB

Tags: jakarta-ee, jta

I want to submit a form with a file, and other simple fields. Because sending a file and saving it in filesystem is typical to web tier, I'm doing it in CDI managed bean. From this CDI managed bean I also call EJB to store other data in database. Saving a file could fail, so I annotated my CDI bean's method with @Transactional (JEE7). What I'm expecting is to rollback EJB's transaction when saving a file fail, but it is not happen. Is it normal behavior? How to rollback EJB's transaction in this case?

```
@Named
@javax.faces.view.ViewScoped
public class LectureCtrl
{
    @Inject LecturesFacade lecturesFacade;
    @Getter @Setter UploadedFile paper;
    @Getter @Setter Lecture lecture;

    @Transactional(rollbackOn={FileNotFoundException.class})
    public void create(Lecture _lecture) throws MessagingException, IOException
    {
        try{
            Long _lectureId = lecturesFacade.create( _lecture );
            //args: file, path, constant filename "abstract"
            WebUtils.handleFileUpload( this.paper, "conferences/"+lecture.getConference().getId()+"/lectures/"+_lectureId, "abstract" );
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public String onSubmitNewLecture(){
        //JSF-specific code
        this.create(this.lecture);
        //JSF-specific code
    }

}


@Stateless
public class LecturesFacade {
    @PersistenceContext EntityManager em;
    @Inject EmailSubsystem emailSubsystem;

    public Long create( Lecture lecture ) throws MessagingException
    {
        em.persist(lecture);
        em.flush();
        em.refresh(lecture);
        Long id = lecture.getId();
        emailSubsystem.sendEmailOnNewLecture(lecture);
        return id;
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
INFO:   java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\konferencje\files\conferences\3\lectures\20\abstract (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:212)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:165)
    at BackingBeans.WebUtils.handleFileUpload(WebUtils.java:154)
    at BackingBeans.LectureCtrl.create(LectureCtrl.java:56)
    ...
```

When `WebUtils.handleFileUpload` fails, I want to also rollback changes made by `lecturesFacade.create`.

**EDIT**

I have annotated my `LectureFacade.create` method with `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.MANDATORY)` and it thrown me an `javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRequiredException` <s>so it looks like CDI transaction is not propagated to EJB transaction</s>.

Comment: How do you mark the transaction as failed? with an annotation? Some code would help us help you.

Comment: No, I just see the java.io.FileNotFoundException has been thrown, the file was not saved, but the data in database has been stored.

Comment: You could simplify things and perhaps avoid dealing with this issue by decoupling creating a lecture and uploading a file associated with a lecture. So the workflow would be 1) create lecture and return id to client 2) client uploads file(s) passing the id as a param. This may be over simplified if you have additional model related logic in side handleFileUpload but since you didn't paste in that code I don't know.

Comment: Also, is your emailSubsystem biz logic part of the TX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that I am invoking @Transactional method (create) from non-transactional method (onSubmitNewLecture) **of the same class**, so @Transactional interceptor will be ommited.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need to define on which checked exceptions to rollback a transactions. The @Transactional annotation has a field called [rollbackOn](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/transaction/Transactional.html#rollbackOn%28%29) to set this

So try the annotation `@Transactional(rollbackOn={FileNotFoundException.class})` - I haven't tried the code, so there might be a typo. The reason why you need to specify this is because FileNotFoundException is a checked exception.

Please do read the documentation I linked, as this is one of the most common errors while using container managed transactions.

### edit

That's strange. Can you try adding IOException to `rollbackOn`? If this doesn't fix it I would check for:

1. Does your DB support transactions? (eg. mysql with myisam doesn't support transactions)
2. Is your DB connection properly configured to use transactions? (on some drivers you can specify to perform an autocommit on each sql statement)
3. Is your container configured properly? Unfortunately, you didn't add the full stacktrace, so I cannot see if the container did create a transaction proxy for `LectureCtrl`
4. Do you have more than one datasource in your application? This only works if you have configured JTA properly (which is mentioned in the tags)

Comment: Please see the comment - by the way I like your profile description "java EE hater"... you're not the only one there :).

Comment: "Sometimes" JEE is really annoying :) IOException didn't helped, I'm using Glassfish4 and Postgresql9.2, only one datasource- managed by JTA, but please take a look at my last edit of original post.